# Interface casting for `Iterable`

Tags: java, generics, interface, polymorphism, javafx

If I have a class called `Cue` that implements `Tickable`. Later, I have an observable list like so: `ObservableList<Cue> oList`. `oList` implements `Iterable<Cue>` (that's just how `ObservableList` is declared).

I have a function that takes `Iterable<Tickable>`. How do I get it to accept `ObservableList<Cue>` Cue is a `Tickable` and ObservableList is a `Iterable`. For some reason, I can't caste between them or upcast automatically. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Would you be so kind and share some code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot cast from an `Iterable<Cue>` to an `Iterable<Tickable>`, because even though a `Cue` is a `Tickable`, an `Iterable<Cue>` is not an `Iterable<Tickable>`, because Java's generics are invariant.

To have a method accept an `ObservableList<Cue>`, have the method parameter type be an `Iterable<Cue>` or use a bounded wildcard -- an `Iterable<? extends Tickable>`.

Answer (score 4):

As rgettman says, you should change the function parameter type to `Iterable<? extends Tickable>`.

This is because `Iterable` is a Producer (it only returns `T` from a method). Therefore, according to the PECS (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`) rule, it should always be parameterized with an `extends` wildcard. In normal usage, there is NO reason to use `Iterable<Something>` instead of `Iterable<? extends Something>`. (The only case where `Iterable<Something>` would be necessary is if you plan to cast it back into its concrete type or something weird like that.)

Answer (score -1):

You *can* do this, by removing the generic type information:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObservableList<Cue> oList = new ObservableList<Cue>();
    naughtyCall(oList);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
static void naughtyCall(ObservableList oList) {
    doSomething(oList);
}

static void doSomething(Iterable<Tickable> iterable) {
    // TODO
}
```

I wouldn't advise this, however! See rgettman's reply for what you *should* do.

---

UPDATE: For anyone interested in playing with this, here is the rest of the code I used to reproduce the OP's situation:

```
class Cue implements Tickable {

}

interface Tickable {

}

static class ObservableList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return null;
    }
}
```